# Understanding upper and lower bounds

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

The following [website](https://math.tutorvista.com/discrete-math/upper-and-lower-bounds.html) explains that an upper bound of the interval $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]$ are numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. I though an upper bound was a number that is greater or equal to every number in that set so $6,7,8$ etc. Is the website wrong?

Comment: That does look to me like an error on that page

Comment: The website looks sloppy to me. In the first place I do not even recognize any set in the notation $[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]$. Secondly, if they mean the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then $1,2,3,4,5$ are no upper bounds of it. Thirdly this set is not an interval.

Comment: @drhab It is supposed to mean an interval, but I do not see how that changes things.

Comment: Also if they mean the interval $[0,6]$ then I do not understand the notation, and also  then $1,2,3,4,5$ are no upper bounds.